# How to get soft delete enabled/disabled status for all keyvault present in one resouce using powershell script

Tags: azure-devops

Can any one please help me how to get soft delete enabled/disabled status for all keyvaults which is present in singel resource group using single powershell

Comment: Is there any code you have tried so far that's not working? Share it here so we can take a look and fix it etc

Comment: $keyvaults=Get-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName 'dev-rg'
foreach($kv in $keyvaults){
    $VaultDetails=Get-AzKEyVault -ResourceGroupName 'dev-rg' -VaultName $kv.VaultName
    if($VaultDetails.EnableSoftDelete -eq $false){
        Write-Host -NoNewline "Soft Delete is Disabled for " 
        Write-Host -NoNewline  $kv.VaultName " is "
        $VaultDetails.EnableSoftDelete
    }} I tried this code but i'm unable to get Disabled keyvaults kindly help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.